# Error_Messages count increasing across all model instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid, mongoid3

I am working on a rails 3.2.9 project with a Mongoid back end. I am trying to create posts and if the post is missing a title and content, the model should fail to save which it does properly. When an object is fixed and passes validation, I save it and now create a new post. If I try to save this one with the missing items, the error count just seems to append the previous one even though these are two different objects.

I am using the error_messages helper from [dynamic_form](https://github.com/joelmoss/dynamic_form) to display my errors. Any Ideas?

Here is a sample error message:

> 152 errors prohibited this post from being saved
>     There were problems with the following fields:
>     Title can't be blank
>     Title can't be blank
>     Title can't be blank
>     Title can't be blank
>     Title can't be blank

The list continues on quite a way. Code is just basic form code:

```
= form_for @post,:as => :post, :url => post_path(:id=>@post.id), :method => :put do |f|
  =f.hidden_field :is_question
  #content        
    .title-page
      %h1 
        New Post        
    = f.error_messages
```

In the model I have:

```
validates_presence_of :title
validates_presence_of :content
```

and my controller method:

```
def publish      
  @post = Post.first(conditions:{_id:params[:post_id]}) 
  @post.assign_attributes(params[:post])

  @post.published=true  

  if @post.save           
    redirect_to "/"
  else
    @video = Video.new    
    render action: "new"
  end    

end
```

Comment: Can you show some code. I also don't know what THE error_messages helper is.

Comment: I added the form code and a link to dynamic_helper which is where the original built-in deprecated error_messages function was moved to.

Comment: How is your validation set up?

Comment: just basic presence validation. Updated question to include

Comment: So it looks like you are persisting something between requests. Can you show the action code?

Comment: Added the action method.

Comment: Is it possible that your models include something like validates_associated so that errors from the @video are repeatedly going into the error display for the @post?

Comment: no, There is no validates_associated in my code. The two validate rules are the only two I have in the model

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the problem, is the project available somewhere (github, sourceforge, etc.)? If not, could you post the code for all relevant models??